# AppCenter POD: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I am getting below error once I will add a pod into xCode project

```
   diff: /Users/PATH/ios/./Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
   diff: /Users/PATH/ios/./Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
   error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

I tried to update pod and then install it again. But result is same.

Manifest.lock from setting:

```
diff "${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile.lock" "${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
    # print error to STDERR
    echo "error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation." >&2
    exit 1
fi
# This output is used by Xcode 'outputs' to avoid re-running this script phase.
echo "SUCCESS" > "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}"
```

Let me know the solution if someone has resolved this issue.

Comment: in terminal are you in project directory where pod file exits  if not then navigate using cd \\path

Comment: I am on path. Now?

Comment: have you tried to delete Podfile.lock and then run pod install ?

Comment: Yeah, already played with delete pod and its related stuff. but didn't work

Comment: Try `pod deintegrate`

Comment: Already did it, but no luck

Comment: same issue here.. were you able to fix this?